# How Can Change My ip When i Use Instaloader

Tags: python, proxy

I use the instaloader and I have a problem
The number of my usernames is high and when I am downloading profiles, my IP is closed whit instagram and I will not be able to make requests for a while.
Can anyone help?
If it is possible to use a proxy, I think it will be good

It must be finished in a short time for these users and I can't use Time.sleep()

Comment: Please be a bit more specific and describe what general task you want to do (link to "Instaloader"), then comes the part where you describe your problem. And provide some sourcecode what you already have tried so far, please.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact way that Instagram bans requests but for changing IP you can use `FreeProxy`.